# Vaadin Grid-Pro handling of ESC while editing cell

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

i am using the vaadin grid-pro web-component in conjunction with flow to let the user edit data in a grid. I noticed that using the ESC key via keyboard let s the user exit the edit mode, in case a cell is edited. So far so good. But how does the ESC key event gets consumed?

I had a look at https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/v24.2.0/packages/grid-pro/src/vaadin-grid-pro-inline-editing-mixin.js#L88 where the ESC key gets handled, stopping the edit state. But there is no stopPropagation() of that event.

Having additionally a vaadin-button with an attached ESC shortcut fires indeed. How can i prevent the button shortcut from firing? (hoping that also the keydown event is used; else things get even more complicated)

Any hint appreciated,
Dan

Comment: To be specify, having  a vaadin-button below the grid-pro on the same page....

Answer (score 0):

If you add shortcut listener to GridPro that stops the propagation, it should work. At least in simple case I had it seems to solve the issue.

```
    Shortcuts.addShortcutListener(grid, e -> {}, Key.ESCAPE).listenOn(grid).setEventPropagationAllowed(false);
```

Comment: Cheers Tatu, this answer is working! Attaching a shortcutListener to the grid does the jop. However, now all ESC are prevented from propagation, even if the grid is not in "edit" mode. I experimented a bit. In 'cell-edit-started' i set eventPropagation(false) and in the esc-handler i set it to 'true' again. This works fine but two ESCs are needed in case the grid is no longer in edit mode (last item). Furthermore, isn't that a very hackish way of handling the esc? (Attaching to grid.getEditor().addXXXListener() does not work at all)